# Specializing a template class member function by type

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I'm trying to specialize a member function on a templated class by a type trait of it's template parameter, but my forward declaration is apparently incorrect.  Is there an easy fix?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class TTest{
public:
  T data;

  // edited to comment this out, template<typename U>
  bool operator !=(const TTest& other) const;
};

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, bool>::type
TTest<T>::operator !=(const TTest<T>& other) const{
  return true;
}

template<typename T>
bool TTest<T>::operator !=(const TTest<T>& other) const{
  return false;
}

int main(){
  TTest<size_t> t1;
  TTest<int> t2;
}
```

Clang tells me:

```
templateTest.cpp:13:11: error: out-of-line definition of 'TTest::operator!='
  differs from the declaration in the return type
TTest<T>::operator !=(const TTest<T>& other) const{
          ^
templateTest.cpp:8:8: note: previous declaration is here
  bool operator !=(const TTest& other) const;
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: This code makes no sense. The member template has *no* dependency on the template parameter, so there's nothing to specialize.

Comment: Do you realize that `const TTest& other` means `const TTest<T>& other` in you rmember template?

Comment: You can't partially specialize a function template. If you want a version for unsigned T and non-unsigned T, then you either need to overload + SFINAE or partially specialize the whole class template.

Comment: @Kerrek I simplified the code.  Depending on whether T is signed or unsigned, the implementation of operator != will be different.  Edit: Whoops, the typename U bit was leftover from one attempt at fixing it.  I'll edit the Q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the whole `enable_if` shebang is part of the function signature (or I don't really understand the errors). I can get the code to compile and behave as you want if I change it to

```
template <typename T>
class TTest{
public:
  T data;

  template<typename U>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, bool>::type
  operator !=(const TTest<U>& other) const;

  template<typename U>
  typename std::enable_if<not std::is_unsigned<U>::value, bool>::type
  operator !=(const TTest<U>& other) const;
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, bool>::type
TTest<T>::operator !=(const TTest<U>&) const{
  return true;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
typename std::enable_if<not std::is_unsigned<U>::value, bool>::type
TTest<T>::operator !=(const TTest<U>&) const{
  return false;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17e24e2ae411bef5). Of course, this gets a lot less repetitive if you define those operators inline.

A better approach might be to dispatch to different private implementations of the operator logic based on the traits of `T`. This removes all the SFINAE verbosity from your code.

```
template <typename T>
class TTest{
public:
  T data;

  bool operator!=(const TTest& other) const
  {
      return not_equal_to(other, typename std::is_unsigned<T>::type());
  }

private:
  bool not_equal_to(TTest const&, std::true_type) const
  {
      return true;
  }

  bool not_equal_to(TTest const&, std::false_type) const
  {
      return false;
  }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/896fc02018487985)

Comment: The first answer seems to work, but I have 2 questions:  if I inline those definitions, I get ambiguous/unable to infer errors (depending if I i use <typename U = T> or <typename U>.  Any idea why?  Second, I don't really want to compare TTests of different types, but this approach seems to allow it.  Any way around that?

Comment: I'm not [getting any errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0db61b7bcec2cfd5) with gcc or clang with inline definitions. You cannot get rid of `template<typename U>` because template argument deduction is required for SFINAE to work. To ensure you don't end up comparing different types, you could add `static_assert(std::is_same<T,U>::value, "")` within the definitions. Anyway, I recommend you not use `enable_if` at all and follow the second approach, unless something prevents you from doing that.

Comment: Whoops, I missed a couple pieces inlining it here, works on my machine as well, thanks.  Why do you prefer the second approach?  Less template noise?

Comment: @BenJones Yep, less verbose and no need for `template<typename U>`

Comment: I assume that, there is no cost for that extra parameter once things get inlined?

Comment: @BenJones There's no guarantee of course, but I'd be very surprised if the optimizer decided not to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a member function template of you class template and you are trying to specialize it as a member function. That's not going to fly. Also, the return types differ although end up evaluating to the same thing.

I don't know what you are trying to attempt as the type `U` of the member function template isn't even deduced (did you mean the argument to be of type `TTest<U>`?). If you want to specialize your member based on a trait, I think you'll either need t *overload* the operator or use a different approach (e.g., delegating the implementation to a specialized class template):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class TTest{
public:
  T data;

  template<typename U>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<U>::value, bool>::type
  operator !=(const TTest<U>& other) const;

  template<typename U>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, bool>::type
  operator !=(const TTest<U>& other) const;
};

template <typename T>
template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<U>::value, bool>::type
TTest<T>::operator !=(const TTest<U>& other) const {
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, bool>::type
TTest<T>::operator !=(const TTest<U>& other) const {
    return false;
}

int main(){
  TTest<unsigned int> t1;
  TTest<int> t2;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << "t1 != t1: " << (t1 != t1) << '\n'
            << "t1 != t2: " << (t1 != t2) << '\n'
            << "t2 != t1: " << (t2 != t1) << '\n'
            << "t2 != t2: " << (t2 != t2) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: In your class declaration, he would have done template<typename U = T> instead. Then that makes sense (and would work). Readability on the other end ....

Answer (score 1):

Tag dispatching is the clean way to do this:

```
template <typename T>
class TTest{
  bool not_equal( const ITest& other, std::true_type /* is unsigned */ ) const;
  bool not_equal( const ITest& other, std::false_type /* is unsigned */ ) const;
public:
  T data;

  bool operator !=(const TTest& other) const {
    return not_equal( other, std::is_unsigned<T>() );
  }
};
```

now simply implement the two `TTest<T>::not_equal` overloads.  Only the one that is actually called for a given `T` will be compiled past basic parsing.